# rm working with curl but not with rcurl

Tags: r, curl, rcurl

on the command line I have:

```
curl -u user:pass sftp://xx.xx.xx.20:22/ -k --quote "-rm /test.txt"
```

and in R I have:

```
curlPerform(url="sftp://xx.xx.xx.20:22/", prequote="rm /test.txt", ssl.verifypeer = FALSE, userpwd = "user:pass")
```

As far as I can tell the two are identical, and I see the directory listing output when I execute both. However, when I execute from the command line `test.txt` gets removed. When I execute in R the output is followed by

```
OK
 0
```

and `test.txt` remains on the remote machine.

Comment: I'm not sure of the difference between `--quote` and `prequote`, but you started `--quote` with `-rm` and started `prequote` with `rm` (without the hyphen).

Comment: Good catch. It works in R with `postquote`. So I think that the dash in curl is the same as postquote in rcurl.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works.

```
curlPerform(url="sftp://xx.xx.xx.20:22/", postquote="rm /test.txt", ssl.verifypeer = FALSE, userpwd = "user:pass")
```

So I am assuming that `postquote` mimics the dash before the command in `curl`. I would love if someone could verify that.